# Sort/reduce Object by key

Tags: typescript, sorting, reduce

I am getting data in the following struture:

```
[{type: 'banana', value: 1}, {type: 'apple', value: 1}, {type: 'banana', value: 4}]
```

I want to "combine" data by type looking like this:

```
[{type: 'banana', value: [1, 4]}, {type: 'apple', value: [1]}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  Which arrays should be sorted and by what criteria?  (Your output is an array of objects, each of which holds an array of values; is it only the inner arrays which should be sorted?) Are you looking for an iterative/functional approach? Do you care about performance? Have you looked for existing questions that are similar but haven't quite done what you wanted?  I could suggest something like [this *somewhat* functional approach](https://tsplay.dev/NV3O7m) but I don't know if it actually does what you want or how you want to do it. Pls clarify, thx

Comment: Thank you! This is what i wanted. I tried myself, but I am not into reduce function. The missing thing was to use "Object.entries()" to solve this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The general approach I'd take here is to convert your input into an object whose keys are the `type` property and whose values are arrays of the corresponding `value` properties.  Here's an iterative way to do that:

```
const input = [
  { type: 'banana', value: 1 },
  { type: 'apple', value: 1 },
  { type: 'banana', value: 4 }
];

const acc: Record<string, number[]> = {}
for (const el of input) {
  if (!(el.type in acc)) // the first time you see this type
    acc[el.type] = []; // initialize the array
  acc[el.type].push(el.value);
};
```

Once you have that, you can iterate the entries of this object with [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), sort the value arrays, and build your output:

```
const output = [];
for (const [type, value] of Object.entries(acc)) {
  value.sort((a, b) => a - b); // numeric sort
  output.push({ type, value });
}
```

That produces the desired output:

```
console.log(output);
/*
[{
  "type": "banana",
  "value": [ 1, 4 ]
}, {
  "type": "apple",
  "value": [ 1 ]
}] 
*/
```

---

You could refactor to use functional array methods instead of `for` loops:

```
const output = Object.entries(input
  .reduce<Record<string, number[]>>(
    (acc, el) => ((acc[el.type] ??= []).push(el.value), acc), {}
  )).map(
    ([type, value]) => ({ type, value: value.sort((a, b) => a - b) })
  );
```

which is essentially the same algorithm (and is still imperative, mutating `acc` and `acc[el.type]`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=7&ts=4.9.5#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkvAPbBQAuSAlsDAK5UC8SA2oUXkhQJ4wQAuJAHIARiFChhAGiQA3TPUFIAjEgC+0jkVzc+y4SBgwMEGfMXK1m7V178hYic-MKMSoQBYNHALoBufA5QSFgEZABJCggAJxAKajlkAk5iMkokBHghACUIUhiAEwAeShjaAHNZYHowUVjWXwA+JBZcdVsAMxIYpAAKUnIqCAwkEk6aOkYASjxbImoJvoBCPpGAOntkWkz4eGnp+c4s1g2t31a2AKOTs-1fdYYoAAs1jHW3JWnA1PUfzkGGRIjAYzCu-yI3V6A3SVFYW1knwgF3GSAA8qIAFb5CjrCDACjlaB9LIHOapIhI9ZQHoUPok2SiWZMFogJAAWiQTIhnGBFFBj3oLz6ugRFncyHU31sHVSgJIpnWGBIFT6fNB0tSAHoAFS2VgpCkAIi2RqERvEkhARq0FKQRqRZrYqlk3l8MtkhtSJv0TqNRhMEBtRwdlidrFUSHdvwuth1WqCRA6wXA0DgiCQAFkSJQMDwAGL0YDwBJkTDkgGwsYgxiXDHYkt4glEqB9Wigo7rGIQQr0RDFPIFEplSrVWr1GKNJpNPpHIgkvayEbMlr027vc5IAD8W5YjWmguFGyR01kpM9sopB3WYCMs7t8-h+kRll8K-6ouf4o834g1Npa6Mu+bKckyGiHHa0q2PKirKqq6ozIEHDJuoQA)